# The random error term is assumed to follow the normal distribution with a mean of 0 in linear regression at each point in x axis

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science

while going through http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Simple_Linear_Regression_Analysis
[image]

They have plotted a normal distribution at X=65 and X=90 and say that error term follow a normal distribution , since linear regression is a function that out puts only one value for a given X , how did they plot the distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend posting this question on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

That being said, what the example is trying to explain is that each individual value of X will return a prediction and an error term. The error terms generated for all X should follow a normal distribution with mean 0. Here, 65 and 90 are just examples of possible values of X.